# SQL to group on/off (bit) together to calculate a duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008+
Not sure how to ask the question so here is some sample data:

```
case_id start_time          timer_name  type    value   duration
8386    2013-02-01 19:25:52 Patient In  25      1       NULL
8386    2013-02-01 20:18:31 Patient Out 25      0       NULL
8386    2013-02-01 20:13:13 Anes. Start 26      1       NULL
8386    2013-02-01 20:18:37 Anes. Stop  26      0       NULL
8386    2013-02-01 20:13:25 Induction   27      1       NULL
8386    2013-02-01 20:18:41 Emergence   27      0       NULL
8386    2013-02-01 20:13:31 Incision    28      1       NULL
8386    2013-02-01 20:18:45 Closing     28      0       NULL
8451    2013-02-06 18:37:44 Anesthesia  1       1       NULL
8451    2013-02-06 18:37:48 Incision    1       1       NULL
8451    2013-02-06 18:05:32 Patient In  25      1       NULL
8451    2013-02-06 18:07:41 Anes. Start 26      1       NULL
8451    2013-02-06 18:11:00 Induction   27      1       NULL
8451    2013-02-06 18:11:54 Emergence   27      0       NULL
8451    2013-02-06 18:11:20 Incision    28      1       NULL
```

Here is the SQL I use to generate this list:

```
SELECT        case_id, start_time, timer_name, type, value, duration
FROM          dbo.event AS ev WITH (nolock)
WHERE         (type IN (1, 2, 3, 25, 26, 27, 28)) AND (defunct = 'N')
ORDER BY      case_id, type, start_time
```

What I need to do is group the types together, ordered by case_id, type, and start_time and then calculate the duration between the first entry with a 1 value and the very next one with a 0 value of the same type.
In the above data, case 8386 should have the following data:

```
8386    2013-02-01 19:25:52 Patient In  25      1       52:39
8386    2013-02-01 20:13:13 Anes. Start 26      1       5:24
8386    2013-02-01 20:13:25 Induction   27      1       5:16
8386    2013-02-01 20:13:31 Incision    28      1       5:14
```

Hopefully I did the math right. The duration does not need to be in that format. I expect the number of seconds is best but this format is easier to read in the question. It also does not matter what name is displayed in the timer_name field.

Understand that I may get multiple 1 values for a type in a row or multiple 0 values in a row. I need to link the first 1 with the first 0 and calculate that duration then look for the next 1, etc. This means that there may be several groupings per type, per case. If there is no 0 value found for a 1 value then I will use the case_end_time that I can pull from another table.

Comment: Is this SQLServer, or another RDBMS?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008. Added that to the question as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of the query uses a correlated subquery to find the next start time according to your logic.  In SQL Server 2012, this would use the `lead()` function, but that is not available:

```
select case_id, start_time, timer_name, type, value, duration,
       (select top 1 start_time
        from event e2
        where e2.case_id = e.case_id and e2.type = e.type and e2.value = 0 and
              e2.start_time > e.start_time
        order by start_time desc
       ) - start_time as duration
from event e
WHERE (type IN (1, 2, 3, 25, 26, 27, 28)) AND (defunct = 'N') and value = 1
```

Your example does not have multiple "0"s.  If you only want the first one, we can find it using `row_number()`:

```
select case_id, start_time, timer_name, type, value, duration,
       (next_start_time - start_time) as duration
from (select case_id, start_time, timer_name, type, value, duration,
             (select top 1 start_time
              from event e2
              where e2.case_id = e.case_id and e2.type = e.type and e2.value = 0 and
                    e2.start_time > e.start_time
              order by start_time desc
             ) as next_start_time,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by case_id, type order by start_time) as seqnum
      from event e
      WHERE (type IN (1, 2, 3, 25, 26, 27, 28)) AND (defunct = 'N') and value = 1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: I am still looking at it as this looks like the right direction but running that SQL as is always returns a next_start_time/duration as null. doesn't the where clause of value = 0 filter out all the 1's so that the "select top 1...e2.value = 1..." will never return anything?

Comment: @mdutra . . . I flipped the values of 0 and 1.  I just fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have to use a bunch of stuff, first, to get the first 1 and 0 you need to use a ROW_NUMBER function partitioned by value, in this way you cant use a where clause to filter by row = 1. At this point you will have the first of 1 an 0 of each case. If you do this in to separated queries the you can join them and make the difference function between the two dates. Some thing like this:

```
    SELECT 
      case_id, type, DATEDIFF(mm, a.start_time, b.start_time) duration 
    FROM 
       (SELECT        case_id, start_time, timer_name, type, value, duration
        FROM          dbo.event AS ev WITH (nolock)
        WHERE       (type IN (1, 2, 3, 25, 26, 27, 28)) AND (defunct = 'N') 
            AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type, value ORDER BY case_id, type) = 1 --Get the first row only
            AND TYPE = 0 -- And the ones of type 0
       ) a INNER JOIN   
       (SELECT        case_id, start_time, timer_name, type, value, duration
        FROM          dbo.event AS ev WITH (nolock)
        WHERE       (type IN (1, 2, 3, 25, 26, 27, 28)) AND (defunct = 'N') 
            AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type, value ORDER BY case_id, type) = 1 --Get the first row only
            AND TYPE = 1 -- And the ones of type 1          
       ) b
   ON
    a.case_id = b.case_id AND
    a.[type] = b.[type]
```

I haven't test it, but that's the idea